# How to insert another component between the Label and TextField in the ExtJS TextField component?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

The `TextField` that is supplied by ExtJS 4.2.1 is basically a `Label` and a `TextField` inside a `Container` set to layout `hbox`.

I need to insert a `ComboBox` in between the `Label` and the `TextField` inside the `Container`.

I have tried to `extend` the `TextField` class but can't find anything that concretely shows the appropriate syntax for adding a Component to another Components hierarchy.

Can someone please post an answer code snippet or link to something that explains to someone that is brand new to ExtJS how to extend a component and modify it like I am trying to?

I just need to be pointed in the right direction and I think I can run with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Ext.form.field.FieldContainer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer)

Here is the simplest example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'FieldContainer Example',
    width: 550,
    bodyPadding: 10,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        fieldLabel: 'Last Three Jobs',
        labelWidth: 100,
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'combo',
                store: {
                fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
                data : [
                    {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
                    {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
                    {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
                ]
            },
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'abbr',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            xtype: 'splitter'
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            flex: 1
        }]
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

You can also made the fieldContainer act as a single field. Quick explanation:

- mixin the `Ext.form.field.Field`
- set the inner fields `submitValue` to `false`

Comment: I didn't use your answer directly, but it pointed me in the right direction! Thanks very much for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer provided by @sra this is what I ended up with. Code extracted from Sencha Architect.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    height: 250,
    width: 680,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'My Form',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    height: 22,
                    layout: {
                        align: 'stretch',
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
                    fieldLabel: 'Label',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            fieldLabel: 'Label',
                            hideLabel: true
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            flex: 1,
                            fieldLabel: 'Label',
                            hideLabel: true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```